# Reliably navigating to correct function definition with tags in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tags, function-declaration

So I've been using [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) with Emacs to navigate my way around a Linux kernel driver I'm trying to understand.  I just spent a day debugging a problem which boiled down to me reading the wrong function definition, because `foo()` was defined (differently) in two separate files, and using `M-.` to navigate to the function definition took me to the irrelevant one of the two possible options.  Is there a way to reliably navigate to a function definition in Emacs?  I've given Vim a try with `C-]` and that seems to take me to the correct function definition, but I'm not normally a Vim user.  So I'm looking for an Emacs specific solution, not a "switch from Emacs to Vim".

Comment: Do you use the same ctags database? If so then emacs has the same information, so it should be able to distinguish between the definitions. Ask the gurus on [emacs help](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gnu.emacs.help). There are also Emacs developers there and since Emacs is written in C they should know about how to use tags efficiently.

Comment: @Tom Yes I'm using the same ctags file for both vim and emacs.

Comment: I see, then it should work, theoretically. I suggest asking the emacs help list if you don't get an answer here.